# NullPointerException on dismiss DialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, android-dialogfragment

I get quite a lot of errors in crashlitycs when I try to dismiss a DialogFragment. This is the error that I get:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler android.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null object reference
```

The line were I am getting is this one `showGenericError { activity?.onBackPressed() }`

```
viewLifecycleOwner.observe(viewModel.showErrorAndExit, {
    showGenericError { activity?.onBackPressed() }
})
```

and here is the method that initalize the dialog:

```
fun showGenericError(actionOnDismiss: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
    val manager = childFragmentManager

    if (popUpErrorCard == null) {
        popUpErrorCard = PopupCard.Builder(R.string.button_try_later)?.apply {
            setDescription(R.string.error_card_description_text)
            setTitle(R.string.subscribe_error_dialog_title)
            setImage(R.drawable.channels_error_popup)
        }.build()?.apply {
            setDismissListener(object : PopupCard.DismissListener {
                override fun onDismiss() {
                    actionOnDismiss?.invoke()
                }
            })
        }
    }

    if (popUpErrorCard?.isAdded == false && popUpErrorCard?.isVisible == false && manager.findFragmentByTag(ERROR_DIALOG_TAG) == null) {
        popUpErrorCard?.show(manager, ERROR_DIALOG_TAG)
        manager.executePendingTransactions()
    }
}
```

The line where I am getting the error is `actionOnDismiss?.invoke()`

And finally the DialogFragment is this one:

```
class PopupCard private constructor() : DialogFragment() {

private lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog
private var negativeListener: View.OnClickListener? = null
private var positiveListener: View.OnClickListener? = null
private var dismissLitener: DismissListener? = null

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
    val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_card, null)

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    arguments?.let args@{ bundle ->
        val negativeText: Int? = bundle.getInt(NEGATIVE_BUTTON_TEXT)

        if (negativeText != null && negativeText != 0) {
            view.negativeButton.setText(negativeText)
        } else {
            view.negativeButton.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        val image: Int? = bundle.getInt(IMAGE_RESOURCE)
        image?.let {
            view.imageHeader.setImageResource(it)
        } ?: run {
            view.imageHeader.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        val titleRes: Int? = bundle.getInt(TITLE_RES)
        val titleText: String? = bundle.getString(TITLE)
        when {
            !titleText.isNullOrBlank() -> {
                view.title.text = titleText
            }
            titleRes != null && titleRes != 0 -> {
                view.title.setText(titleRes)
            }
            else -> view.title.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        val descriptionRes: Int? = bundle.getInt(DESCRIPTION_RES)
        val descriptionText: String? = bundle.getString(DESCRIPTION)
        when {
            !descriptionText.isNullOrBlank() -> {
                view.description.text = descriptionText
            }
            descriptionRes != null && descriptionRes != 0 -> {
                view.description.setText(descriptionRes)
            }
            else -> view.description.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        val actionPair = bundle.getInt(POSITIVE_BUTTON_TEXT)
        view.positiveButton.setText(actionPair)
    }

    builder.setView(view)

    dialog = builder.create()

    view.positiveButton.setOnClickListener {
        positiveListener?.onClick(it)
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    view.negativeButton.setOnClickListener {
        negativeListener?.onClick(it)
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    return dialog
}

fun setOnPositiveClickListener(listener: View.OnClickListener) {
    this.positiveListener = listener
}

fun setOnNegativeClickListener(listener: View.OnClickListener) {
    this.negativeListener = listener
}

fun setDismissListener(listener: DismissListener) {
    this.dismissLitener = listener
}

override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog)
    dismissLitener?.onDismiss()
}

interface DismissListener {
    fun onDismiss()
}

companion object {

    private const val NEGATIVE_BUTTON_TEXT = "PopupCard#NEGATIVE_BUTTON_TEXT"
    private const val IMAGE_RESOURCE = "PopupCard#IMAGE_RESOURCE"
    private const val TITLE = "PopupCard#TITLE"
    private const val TITLE_RES = "PopupCard#TITLE_RES"
    private const val DESCRIPTION = "PopupCard#DESCRIPTION"
    private const val DESCRIPTION_RES = "PopupCard#DESCRIPTION_RES"
    private const val POSITIVE_BUTTON_TEXT = "PopupCard#POSITIVE_BUTTON_TEXT"
}

class Builder(
    @StringRes private val positiveText: Int
) {

    private var negativeText: Int? = null
    @DrawableRes
    private var image: Int? = null
    @StringRes
    private var titleRes: Int? = null
    private var titleText: String? = null
    @StringRes
    private var descriptionRes: Int? = null
    private var descriptionText: String? = null

    fun setTitle(@StringRes title: Int): Builder {
        this.titleRes = title
        return this
    }

    fun setTitle(title: String): Builder {
        this.titleText = title
        return this
    }

    fun setDescription(@StringRes description: Int): Builder {
        this.descriptionRes = description
        return this
    }

    fun setDescription(description: String): Builder {
        this.descriptionText = description
        return this
    }

    fun setNegativeText(@StringRes negativeText: Int): Builder {
        this.negativeText = negativeText
        return this
    }

    fun setImage(@DrawableRes image: Int): Builder {
        this.image = image
        return this
    }

    fun build(): PopupCard {
        val bundle = Bundle().apply {
            negativeText?.let {
                putInt(NEGATIVE_BUTTON_TEXT, it)
            }
            image?.let {
                putInt(IMAGE_RESOURCE, it)
            }
            titleRes?.let {
                putInt(TITLE_RES, it)
            }
            titleText?.let {
                putString(TITLE, it)
            }
            descriptionRes?.let {
                putInt(DESCRIPTION_RES, it)
            }
            descriptionText?.let {
                putString(DESCRIPTION, it)
            }
            putInt(POSITIVE_BUTTON_TEXT, positiveText)
        }
        return PopupCard().apply {
            arguments = bundle
        }
    }
}
```

}

In the DialogFragment the error is here `dismissLitener?.onDismiss()`

As you can see in all of the lines that are causing the error have safe calls (?) so I don't know why I am getting NullPointerException and I was unable to reproduce it so I cannot give more details about the issue.

Comment: It's likely something in the `onBackPressed()` call itself. Consider examining the complete stacktrace and not just the topmost row.

Comment: onBackPressed is a method that is part of the android sdk is not a custom method.

Comment: Well the `android.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler` call where the NPE occurs is also likely from some platform code. Note that it has the deprecated android.app fragments there and not jetpack androidx.app fragments.

Comment: this is weird since I am using androidx.app  fragments. I don't know who (library or whatever) is using android.app fragments I can show you the imports that I am using if you think that it can help to find the error.

Comment: how are you calling `showGenericError` ? what do you pass in `actionOnDismiss` ?

Comment: I updated the question so you can check how I call it. Basically this code is in a fragment and I call in when a LiveEvent is triggered. actionOnDismiss basically execute the piece of code that you can see when calling showGenericError `activity?.onBackPressed()`

Comment: Can you also share the assignment of viewLifecycleOwner and the viewModel.showErrorAndExit ? I suspect the problem has to do with the DialogFragment, are you using the androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment or android.app.DialogFragment ? If you are using android.app.Dialog fragment and androidx for your other fragments, than the class PopupCard is the culprit most probably.

Comment: `viewLifecycleOwner` comes from `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` and `viewModel.showErrorAndExit` is a `androidx.lifecycle.LiveData`. `PopupCard` is a  `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment` I really tried to find where I am using android but all the classes that I look for where androidx ones.

Comment: activity?.onBackPressed() in most of cases it causes when, your fragment no longer attach to activity, it might be crash due to some other issue. It is related to activity fragment lifecycle.

Comment: @manmohan yeah that's exactly what I've been trying to explain in my answer

Comment: Can you paste the entire exception log including stacktrace into your question?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
    viewLifecycleOwner.observe(viewModel.showErrorAndExit, {
        showGenericError { activity?.onBackPressed() }
})
```

actually be

```
    viewModel.showErrorAndExit.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        showGenericError { activity?.onBackPressed() }
})
```

Comment: this is a extension function that I made and with what I write there is making the same you are recomending.

Answer (score 0):

> I get quite a lot of errors in crashlitycs

I assume that you don't know exact steps to reproduce the crash, do you?
Crash may happen after your Activity is recreated while DialogFragment is still shown. For example: open dialog -> rotate screen -> dismiss dialog.

What will happen after screen rotation? New Activity will be created, DialogFragment will be detached from the old Activity and attached to the new one. But your DialogFragment keeps reference to the old Activity in its `dismissListener` callback. So, you try to call `.onBackPressed()` on Activity which lifecycle stage is "destroyed". That's forbidden in Android framework and that may be reason for your `NullPointerException`.

**So, what can you do with it?**

I see three different solutions here:

1. Best choice from the clean code perspective is *to not keep reference* to an Activity in your DialogFragment. It's a bad practice because even without crashes it may cause memory leaks. Consider using MVVM architecture pattern: you can keep reference to a ViewModel because it's not recreated, it's always the same instance. So in your callback you can call something like `viewModel.closeScreen()` and ViewModel will find current activity and call `.onBackPressed()` on it.
2. Probably best choice for you in this situation is to find your DialogFragment when Activity is recreated and update it's callback. E.g.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val dialog = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG)
    if (dialog != null) {
        dialog.setOnDismissListener {
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

3. And finally what I don't recommend to do (but will probably fix your crash in most cases) is to forbid your Activity to be recreated on screen rotations. Just add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your Activity's attributes in AndroidManifest.xml. But don't forget that there are many reasons why Activity can be recreated and screen rotation is only one of them!

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't have screen rotation allowed in my app. Is always in portrait mode. So the activity won't be recreated at least for screen rotation. Is there any other reason that the activity can be recreated?

Comment: Yes sure. Any configuration changes trigger Activities restart (e.g. language, resolution). Also if your Activity is paused and OS has low memory it will destroy Activity and then recreate from Bundle. This can also be forced via "don't keep activities" flag in developer settings. And I'm pretty sure that automated tests in Google Play may force Activities recreation which can cause your crashes in crashlytics.

Comment: Hey @IbanArriola I would really appreciate if you accept my answer if it helped you. I don't see any other reasons for crashes except for what I've explained.

Answer (score 0):

A quick work-around is to use an Interface/Contract instead of direct access to the hosting Activity, that's a forbidden action in the world of SOLID.
So, instead of:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.observe(viewModel.showErrorAndExit, {
showGenericError { activity?.onBackPressed() }})
```

Use

```
viewLifecycleOwner.observe(viewModel.showErrorAndExit, {
showGenericError { loosedCopuledActivity?.onBackPressTriggered() }})
```

then implement the interface in the parent activity.

```
class SomeHostActivity: AppCompatActivity(), OnBackPressCallback{}
```

And somewhere around define your Interface:

```
interface OnBackPressCallback{
    fun onBackPressTriggered() 
}
```

Also you need to define your loosedCoupledActivity somewhere in the dialog, so we can do it like:

```
fun onActivityCreate(bluhbluh: BluhBluh){
    super.onActivityCreate(bluhbluh)
    if(requireActivity() is OnBackPressCallback){
        loosedCoupledActivity = requireActivity()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment code, I see this:

> ```
> override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
>     super.onDismiss(dialog)
>     dismissLitener?.onDismiss()
> }
> ```

The framework code that calls this method passes in a value retrieved from a `WeakReference`, which means that `dialog` will sometimes be null. Therefore, you must define the method to accept a nullable `DialogInterface?`.

```
override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface?) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog)
    dismissLitener?.onDismiss()
}
```

If you don't make `dialog` nullable, your app will crash any time the system passes a null reference to your `onDismiss()` callback, even if you never actually use the value of `dialog`.

---

From the source code:

```
private static final class ListenersHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<DialogInterface> mDialog;

    public ListenersHandler(Dialog dialog) {
        mDialog = new WeakReference<>(dialog);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case DISMISS:
                ((OnDismissListener) msg.obj).onDismiss(mDialog.get());
                break;
            case CANCEL:
                ((OnCancelListener) msg.obj).onCancel(mDialog.get());
                break;
            case SHOW:
                ((OnShowListener) msg.obj).onShow(mDialog.get());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```